# How do I bind string which is HTML in FreeTextMarker?

Tags: java, html, html-email, freemarker

I need to bind couple of strings and few html snippets. Output HTML should contain data along with HTML(in design).

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your data-model is a `Map<String, Object>`, called `model` (could be bean with getters too of course). Then you should fill the mode like this:

```
model.put("htmlSnippet", HTMLOutputFormat.INSTANCE.fromMarkup("This is <em>HTML</em>!");
model.put("plainTextSnippet", "This is <em>not</em> HTML!");
```

Above, `htmlSnippet` will be a `TemplateHTMLOutputModel` object, not a `String`, so FreeMarker will know that it mustn't be HTML-escaped.

Now if your template is this, and you have HTML auto-escaping enabled (typically done by giving `ftlh` file extension, or with `<#ftl outputFormat='HTML'>` header, or otherwise in the `Configuration`):

```
${htmlSnippet}
${plainTextSnippet}
```

Then the HTML source of the output will be this:

```
This is <em>HTML</em>!
This is &lt;em&gt;not&lt;/em&gt; HTML!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBuilder to get your email-html as String.